# Configuring an XBee S2 for controling AC devices

Tags: configuration, xbee

I have two XBee **S2s**, and I want to configure them to take digital input (3.3 V) from one XBee and get a digital output from another XBee to control the AC devices.

I have tried many XBee configurations for it, but I don't get the desired output.

How do I get this configuration right?

Answer (score 0):

The Series 1 modules support [I/O Line Passing](http://www.digi.com/support/kbase/kbaseresultdetl?id=2188) -- a mode where an input on XBee A can trigger an output on XBee B.

In the case of Series 2 modules, you need to have a host processor on one end which can receive input change notifications (see `ATIC`) and generate an AT command frame to manually change the output pin to match the input pin's state.